# Suggest to the compiler to selectively inline function calls

Tags: c++, inline

Suppose I have the following code:

```
struct Foo {
  void helper() { ... }
  void fast_path() { ...; helper(); ... }
  void slow_path1() { ...; helper(); ... }
  void slow_path2() { ...; helper(); ... }
};
```

The method `fast_path()` is performance critical and so every (reasonable) effort should be made to make it as fast as possible. The methods `slow_path1()` and `slow_path2()` are not performance critical.

From my understanding, a typical compiler might look at this code and decide not to inline `helper()` if it is complex enough, in order to reduce total instruction size, as `helper()` is shared between multiple methods functions. That same compiler might inline `helper()` if the slow-path methods did not exist.

Given our desired performance characteristics, we want the compiler to inline the call to `helper()` inside `fast_path()`, but prefer the compiler's default behavior in `slow_path1()` and `slow_path2()`.

One workaround is to have the slow-path function definitions and the call to `fast_path()` live in separate compilation units, so that the compiler never sees a usage of `helper()` shared with `fast_path()`. But maintaining this separation requires special care and cannot be enforced through the compiler. Plus, the proliferation of files (Foo.h, FooINLINES.cpp, and now also Foo.cpp) is undesirable, and the additional compilation units complicates the build of what perhaps could have been a header-only library.

Is there a better way?

Ideally I'd want a new `do_not_inline_function_calls_inside_me` c++ keyword that I could use like this:

```
  do_not_inline_function_calls_inside_me void slow_path1() { ... }
  do_not_inline_function_calls_inside_me void slow_path2() { ... }
```

Alternatively, a `inline_function_calls_inside_me` keyword, like this:

```
  inline_function_calls_inside_me void fast_path() { ... }
```

Note that these hypothetical keywords decorate the `*_path*()` methods, not the `helper()` method.

An example context where you might have these sorts of performance demands is a programming competition where each participant writes an application that listens to sparse global data broadcasts of types A and B. When type-B broadcasts are received, each application must perform a computation that depends on the sequence of previously broadcasted type-A messages, and submit the computation result to a central server. The first correct responder to each type-B broadcast scores a point. The nature of the computational problem might allow for precomputation to be performed on the type-A updates; there is no advantage to doing those quickly.

Comment: The techniques to prevent a function from being inlined are compiler specific.   Just like the techniques that guarantee a function is inlined.   Anyway, your premise is flawed, and shows a "premature optimisation" mindset.   A scenario in which one function is "performance critical" is so rare in practice, as to be meaningless.   Programmers are much less capable than they think they are of identifying the performance hotspots in their code - that is why tools like profilers exist.

Comment: @Peter Performance critical code paths might be rare in practice, but they do exist. I am particularly interested in gcc.

Comment: With gcc, you can specify `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

Comment: @JoelCornett I've updated my post to better describe why we might want to decorate the caller instead of the callee.

Comment: I added a paragraph at the end that gives an example where my given performance requirements might be reasonable.

Comment: Your work-around using separate compilation units would not work when you use whole-program optimization. Since you are talking about performance optimization, I would always switch this on as it gives the compiler many more options to optimize, e.g. eliminate virtual function calls or propagate constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should not try to be smarter than the compiler. Modern compilers do an awesome job at deciding how to inline functions and humans are notoriously bad at reasoning about this.

In my experience, the best you can do is to have all relevant functions there  as `inline` functions in the same translation unit so the compiler can see their definition and *can* inline them as it sees fit. Levae the final decision whether to inline a given function to the compiler, however, and use “forced inline” very sparingly, unless you have evidence that it has a beneficial effect in a given situation.

To make the compiler's job easier, you can provide it with additional information about your program. In GCC and Clang, you can use [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) for this.

```
struct Foo {
  void helper();
  void fast_path()  __attribute__ ((hot));
  void slow_path1() __attribute__ ((cold));
  void slow_path2() __attribute__ ((cold));
};

inline void Foo::helper()     { … }
inline void Foo::fast_path()  { … }
inline void Foo::slow_path1() { … }
inline void Foo::slow_path2() { … }
```

This will hint the compiler to optimize `Foo::fast_path`more aggressively for speed and `Foo::slow_path1` and `Foo::slow_path2` for small cache footprint. If either of these functions calls `Foo::helper`, it can decide on a case-by-case basis whether to inline it or not. (See the documentation in the linked manual for the precise effect of the annotations.)

An even better way to hint the compiler is to give it actual profiling data. With GCC, you can compile your program with the `-fprofile-generate` option. This will instrument your binary with code that collects profile statistics. Now run your program with a representative set of inputs. Doing so will create a `*.gcda` file with the collected profile data. Now re-compile with the `-fprofile-use` option. GCC will use the collected profile information to decide what paths in your code are hot and how they interact with each other. This technique is known as *profile guided optimization* (PGO).

Of course, if you're worried about such things, first make sure that you enable appropriate optimization levels (`-O2`). Especially template-heavy C+ code (ie, almost everything that uses the standard library or Boost) can generate really ugly machine code when compiled without decent optimization. Also think whether you want to compile `assert`ions into your code (`-DNDEBUG`).

Comment: The hot/cold attributes look like exactly what I wanted. Never knew about them - thanks!

Comment: Regarding your PGO suggestion, however: if you look at my example application in the last paragraph of my post, you'll see that it is not a good candidate for PGO if the type-A updates vastly outnumber the type-B ones.

Comment: Yes, that might be challenging. Maybe you can craft an input sequence for the profiling run that triggers more *B* events? But this is a slippery slope. If the profiling data is hard to collect, staying with the manual attributes is probably your best bet.

Comment: Crafting an input sequence that attempts to give each code-path a frequency proportional to its performance-sensitivity would indeed be a huge challenge. The manual attributes look much more promising.